# Flutter PageView not displaying all the data from database (php)

Tags: flutter

I want to display data from database in pageview, swiping the screen like user1_name -> user1_age -> user2_name -> user2_age -> and so on for all data coming from database, but my code is showing only first user data (only one). In gridview it is showing all the data of database. I am adding the code, please help me what could be modified:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:student/student_pages/student_detail.dart';
import '../utils/constants.dart';

String website = Constants.website;

class UserDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String subjectId;
  const UserDetail({super.key, required this.userId});

  @override
  State<UserDetail> createState() =>
      _UserDetailState();
}

class _UserDetailState extends State<UserDetail> {
  get userId => widget.userId;

  get itemCount => null;
  Future<List> getUserData() async {
    String url = '$website/get_user_data.php';
    var data = {'user_id': userId};
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data);
    var userDetail= jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return userDetail;
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('User Detail'),
        ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(20), //border corner radius
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), //color of shadow
                      spreadRadius: 5, //spread radius
                      blurRadius: 7, // blur radius
                      offset: Offset(0, 2), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                child: Text(
                  'Swip left, right',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var userName = snapshot.data![index]['user_name'];
                          var userAge = snapshot.data![index]['user_age'];
                          return PageView(
                            pageSnapping: true,
                            controller: pageController,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  "$index:- $userName,",
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  '$userAge',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),


           
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the full code for the widget so we can see how you are managing your state when swiping to a new page.

Comment: hi, Eric Su
I have edited the code, please check again

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it at first, but you are returning another `PageView` widget inside your `PageView.builder` widget. It's not good practice to nest PageView widgets inside each other because it will lead to scrolling complications.

Here is the corrected code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:student/student_pages/student_detail.dart';
import '../utils/constants.dart';

String website = Constants.website;

class UserDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String subjectId;
  const UserDetail({super.key, required this.userId});

  @override
  State<UserDetail> createState() => _UserDetailState();
}

class _UserDetailState extends State<UserDetail> {
  get userId => widget.userId;

  get itemCount => null;
  Future<List> getUserData() async {
    String url = '$website/get_user_data.php';
    var data = {'user_id': userId};
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data);
    var userDetail = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return userDetail;
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('User Detail'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), //border corner radius
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), //color of shadow
                      spreadRadius: 5, //spread radius
                      blurRadius: 7, // blur radius
                      offset: Offset(0, 2), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Swip left, right',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        controller: pageController, //use pageController here
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var userName = snapshot.data![index]['user_name'];
                          var userAge = snapshot.data![index]['user_age'];
                          return Column( //don't return another PageView
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  "$index:- $userName,",
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  '$userAge',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I am not getting what I am expecting. It is showing user name and and age in one screen and after swiping the 2nd user name and age in 2nd screen. I want user name in one screen and after swiping the user age in another screen, again after swiping show the 2nd user name and again after swiping show the 2nd user age and next third and so on. Please help me